# How to play some audios with a media player in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have a sentence in a Textbox, I want a MediaPlayer read it from a folder for example. To do it I have written some codes to get each word which the sentence consist of. Now I want to play its audio. But I can not do it. The MediaPlayer only play the last one. I think this is because of preventing the MediaPlayer to play in each loop or doing it very fast. How may I make a pause in it to play and then allow the loop continue again(without using a timer)?

```
string vocab = textBox2.Text.ToLower() + " ";
            string word = null;
            foreach (char c in vocab)
            {
                word += c;
                if (c == ' ')
                {

                    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = ("some url parts for example" + word.TrimEnd() + ".mp3");
                   // MessageBox.Show(word.TrimEnd());
                 word = null;
                }

            }
```

When I uncomment the `// MessageBox.Show(word.TrimEnd());` it plays but I dont want to use a messagebox. thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to manually collect all these file names.

Instead of

```
string vocab = textBox2.Text.ToLower() + " ";
string word = null;
foreach (char c in vocab)
{
   word += c;
   if (c == ' ')
   {
       axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = ("some url parts for example" + word.TrimEnd() + ".mp3");
       word = null;
   }
}
```

you can simply do:

```
string[] fileNames = textBox2.Text
  .ToLower().Split(" ").Select(word => String.Format("C:\some url parts for example\{0}.mp3", word.Trim());
```

It takes the sentence, converts it to lower-case, splits up to an array of words by whitespaces. Then, trims every word and converts it to a path to `mp3` file.

What about **playing audio files consequently**, you can convert your string to a list of files, create it as a playlist and play using the player:

```
string tempPlaylistFilename = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "TemporaryPlaylist.m3u");

string[] fileNames = textBox2.Text
                       .ToLower()
                       .Split(" ")
                       .Select(word => String.Format("C:\some url parts for example\{0}.mp3", word.Trim());

File.WriteAllLines(fileNames)

axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = tempPlaylistFilename;
```

You can save this playlist wherever you want, I just have decided to use temporary folder.

Comment: I have an `axWindowsMediaPlayer1` toolbox on my form, It must play every word from a folder which its name is as same as each words that has been splited. (when I use `xWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = (".../folderName/" + word+ ".mp3");` the `xWindowsMediaPlayer1` plays the word which is in that path. But I dont know who to do it with all the word because I could play each word itself and when Iuse a loop it just plays the last word.

Comment: @user1605859 I know. That's why I have shown you how to use playlist :)

Comment: But there are some errors in the code. Perhaps I am confused by the URL.

Comment: @user1605859 What are the errors? What Visual Studio version do you use?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @user1605859 Oh, ok, I have used C# 6.0 features which are only supported by Visual Studio 2015. I have updated my answer.